# ASP.NET MVC3 Custom Membership Provider - The membership provider name specified is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, membership-provider

I'm implementing a custom membership provider, and everything seems to go swimmingly until I create a MembershipUser object. At that point, I receive the error:

> The membership provider name specified
>   is invalid. Parameter name:
>   providerName

In `web.config` the membership key is

```
<membership defaultProvider="MembersProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="MembersProvider" type="Members.Providers.MembersProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="DeviceDatabase" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

When creating the MembershipUser object from my custom User class:

```
    public static MembershipUser ToMembershipUser(User user)
    {
        MembershipUser member = new MembershipUser
            ("MembersProvider"
            , user.Name
            , user.Id
            , user.EmailAddress
            , user.PasswordQuestion
            , user.Comment
            , user.IsApproved
            , user.IsLockedOut
            , user.DateCreated
            , user.LastLoginDate ?? DateTime.MinValue
            , user.LastActivityDate ?? DateTime.MinValue
            , user.LastPasswordChangedDate ?? DateTime.MinValue
            , user.LastLockoutDate ?? DateTime.MinValue
            );

        return member;
    }
```

*(I realize I could probably just inherit my User class from MembershipUser, but it's already part of an existing class hierarchy. I honestly think this is the first time I've encountered a legitimate need for for multiple inheritance!)*

My feeling is that the `new MembershipUser(...)` providerName parameter is supposed to match what's set in `web.config`, but, since they match already, I'm at a loss as to how to proceed.

Is there a convenient way to get the name of the active membership provider in code?

I'm starting to think that using the built-in membership system is overkill and more trouble than it's worth.

**Edit**
Not sure if it's relevant, but the custom membership provider class is in a class library, not the main WAP project.

**Update**
Here's the contents of the `System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider` object as show in the VS2010 command window:

```
>eval System.Web.Security.Membership.Provider
{Members.Providers.MembersProvider}
    [Members.Providers.MembersProvider]: {Members.Providers.MembersProvider}
    base {System.Configuration.Provider.ProviderBase}: {Members.Providers.MembersProvider}
    ApplicationName: null
    EnablePasswordReset: true
    EnablePasswordRetrieval: false
    MaxInvalidPasswordAttempts: 5
    MinRequiredNonAlphanumericCharacters: 0
    MinRequiredPasswordLength: 6
    PasswordAttemptWindow: 10
    PasswordFormat: Function evaluation was aborted.
    PasswordStrengthRegularExpression: Cannot evaluate expression because debugging information has been optimized away .
    RequiresQuestionAndAnswer: Cannot evaluate expression because debugging information has been optimized away .
    RequiresUniqueEmail: Cannot evaluate expression because debugging information has been optimized away .
```

**Update 2**

This just randomly started working, which means I changed something but can't remember what it was. Stupid brain.  I'll accept the only answer that's been posted and update this if I figure out what the problem was.

Comment: Can you try and make `type="Members.Providers.MembersProvider"` fully quantified by putting an assembly at the end and see how that works

Comment: Could you expand on "put an assembly at the end"?

Comment: Edit, ignore that. Your edit with the trace proves it is loading the correct type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the solution yet, but with the two following functions you can at least get an idea what is registered:

```
Membership.Provider

Membership.Providers
```

I did inherit my User class from MembershipUser for some reason, but I'm pretty sure I had a good reason for it :-)

Comment: Yep, it'd certainly be more convenient! It would be nice if there were a convenient, non-reflection way to copy one type to another if they have the same property names and types. Guess I could make a T4 template for that, but it feels sloppy.

Comment: Accepted since it's the only answer; also I wasn't aware of the `.Provider(s)` properties which provided some useful insight. Thanks.

Comment: I did some more googling, but as far as I can see, there is no other way the to inherit from MembershipUser.

Comment: As for copying properties across, you can use something like AutoMapper: http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 6):

I used Membership.Provider.Name to get the correct name parameter

```
    public static MembershipUser GetUserFromEntity(this UserEntity userEntity)
    {
        return new MembershipUser(
                Membership.Provider.Name, 
                userEntity.Username,
                userEntity.PartitionKey,
                userEntity.Email,
                userEntity.PasswordQuestion,
                userEntity.Comment,
                userEntity.IsApproved,
                userEntity.IsLockedOut,
                userEntity.CreationDate,
                userEntity.LastLoginDate,
                userEntity.LastActivityDate,
                userEntity.LastPasswordChangedDate,
                userEntity.LastLockedOutDate
            );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, using Membership.Provider.Name as opposed to this.Name fixed a "The membership provider name specified is invalid" error during testing. This error only started when I started directly calling my custom provider through an instance I created as opposed to accessing it through the Membership class.